# php :select column in array with Undefined index error

Tags: php, arrays

I want get column in PHP array
`$slider` is this :

```
        array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["image"]=>
    string(32) "themes/public/slideshow/ads1.jpg"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["title1"]=>
    string(1) "."
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["image"]=>
    string(32) "themes/public/slideshow/ads2.jpg"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["title1"]=>
    string(1) "."
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["image"]=>
    string(32) "themes/public/slideshow/ads3.jpg"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    ["title1"]=>
    string(1) "."
  }
}
```

when i want get column of this array php has error `Undefined index` !
this error is exist in server but isnt exist in localhost!

```
    foreach ($slider as $slide)
    {

        $s = $slide['image'];

        ?>


        <div>
            <img u="image" src2="<?php echo $url . "/$s" ?> " />
        </div>

        <?php

    }

    ?>
```

> Undefined index: image  in this line : $s = $slide['image'];

Comment: `<img src2>` ??? that will **not** work; remove the `2`, and what is `u=` supposed to represent?

Comment: @NikhilVaghela Undefined offset: 6   in ->foreach ($slider[6] as $slide)

Comment: @Fred-ii- !syntax is correct !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `isset` to check if given key exists

```
$slider = array (
    array (
    'image' => "themes/public/slideshow/ads1.jpg"
),
    array (
    'title1'=>"."
),
    array (
    'image'=>"themes/public/slideshow/ads2.jpg"
),
    array (
    'title1'=>"."
),
    array (
    'image'=>"themes/public/slideshow/ads3.jpg"
),
    array (
    'title1'=>"."
),
);

$url = 'http://example.com';
foreach ($slider as $slide)
{
    if (isset($slide['image'])) {
        $s = $slide['image'];
        echo $url . '/' . $s . '<br />';
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://phpio.net/s/1ap)**

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is pretty normal, due to the way you `$slider` is built!

When you do `foreach ($slider as $slide)` you get successive `$slide` which are alternatively containing `image` **or** `title1`: in other words one of two members **don't contain** the `image` index you're looking for.

In fact, here is how you should build your array:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["image"]=>
    string(32) "themes/public/slideshow/ads1.jpg"
    ["title1"]=>
    string(1) "."
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["image"]=>
    string(32) "themes/public/slideshow/ads2.jpg"
    ["title1"]=>
    string(1) "."
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["image"]=>
    string(32) "themes/public/slideshow/ads3.jpg"
    ["title1"]=>
    string(1) "."
  }
}
```

Then you may work as you expected...

Answer (score 0):

Your array contains other arrays, each of your array contains a single row. But the indexes of all these sub-arrays is not the same. Sometimes it is `image`, sometimes it is `title1`. but in your code, you only use the `image` key,  on line `$s = $slide['image'];` even if it is a `title1` one...

So check if the key exists before using it :

```
if (array_key_exists('image', $slide) {
    $s = $slide['image'];
    ?>
    <div>
        <img u="image" src2="<?php echo $url . "/$s" ?> " />
    </div>
    <?php
}
```